# Pandas turn level1 of index to level 0 of column

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I couldn't find the solution to this anywhere, so I am asking it here.

I have a data frame that looks like this. Here `A` and `B` are the indices of MultiIndex and `C`,`D` are column headers.

```
A   B   C   D
a1  b1  0   4
a1  b2  1   5
```

How can I switch the 1st level of index to make it a 0th level of columns so that I get something like this -

```
A/B        
          b1            b2
      C        D     C      D
a1    0        4     1      5
```

It seems like a simple operation on a dataframe but I can not find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), but then is necessary change `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.unstack().swaplevel(1,0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
B  b1    b2   
    C  D  C  D
A             
a1  0  4  1  5
```

Or solution from @piRSquared:

```
df = df.stack().unstack(0).T
```

Comment: `df.stack().unstack(0).T`, I'm assuming `A` and `B` are already in the index.